# Why is yiic message ignoring yii::t() new strings?

Tags: yii

On my index controller I have the following new translations:

```
$this->pageTitle = yii::t('sitename','what we do');
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerMetaTag(yii::t('sitename','foo bar foo foo bar'), 'description');
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerMetaTag(yii::t('sitename','foo, bar, foo, bar'), 'keywords');
```

I then go to my command line, I run:

```
./yiic message ../app/messages/config.php
```

I get:

> Saving messages to
>   /Users/user/Sites/sitename.dev/app/messages/en/sitename.php...nothing
>   new...skipped.

Here's my app messages/`config.php` file:

```
/**
 * This is the configuration for generating message translations
 * for the Yii framework. It is used by the 'yiic message' command.
 */
return array(
    'language'=>'pt',
    'sourcePath'=>dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'../..',
    'messagePath'=>dirname(__FILE__),
    'languages'=>array('en'),
    'fileTypes'=>array('php'),
    'overwrite'=>true,
    'exclude'=>array(
        '.svn',
        '/app/data/i18n',
        '/htdocs',
        '/app/tests',
        '/app/messages',
        '/app/config',
    ),
);
```

Can anyone help me out figuring why this is happening please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it.

Letter **case** IS VERY IMPORTANT.
I've wrongly used `yii::t();` instead of `Yii::t();`